# Python breaks parsing json with characters \"

Tags: python, json, parsing, ujson

I'm trying to parse json string with an escape character (Of some sort I guess)

```
{
    "publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""
}
```

Parser parses well if I remove the character `\"` from the string,

the exceptions raised by different parsers are,

**json**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 17 column 20 (char 392)
```

**ujson**

```
ValueError: Unexpected character in found when decoding object value
```

How do I make the parser to escape this characters ?

update:
[image] 
*ps. json is imported as ujson in this example*

[image]

This is what my ide shows

comma is just added accidently, it has no trailing comma at the end of json, json is valid

[image]

the string definition.

Comment: How did you define the input string? When you *print* the string, do you still see the backslashes? I cannot reproduce this at all.

Comment: If the input string is within Python source, you may need to escape metacharacters there first.  Consider raw strings if that's the case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the comma is added accidentally, the issue is the characters `/"`

Comment: can you show us the method where you are initiating the parse?

Comment: @Marty: note that your screenshot shows you are defining a *Python string*, so the `\"` is *interpreted as a Python string literal escape*. The backlashes are gone in the actual value you produced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost certainly did not define properly escaped backslashes. If you define the string properly the JSON parses *just fine*:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_str = r'''
... {
...     "publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""
... }
... '''  # raw string to prevent the \" from being interpreted by Python
>>> json.loads(json_str)
{u'publisher': u'"O\'Reilly Media, Inc."'}
```

Note that I used a *raw string literal* to define the string in Python; if I did not, the `\"` would be interpreted by Python and a regular `"` would be inserted. You'd have to *double* the backslash otherwise:

```
>>> print '\"'
"
>>> print '\\"'
\"
>>> print r'\"'
\"
```

Reencoding the parsed Python structure back to JSON shows the backslashes re-appearing, with the `repr()` output for the string using the same double backslash:

```
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(json_str))
'{"publisher": "\\"O\'Reilly Media, Inc.\\""}'
>>> print json.dumps(json.loads(json_str))
{"publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""}
```

If you did not escape the `\` escape you'll end up with unescaped quotes:

```
>>> json_str_improper = '''
... {
...     "publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""
... }
... '''
>>> print json_str_improper

{
    "publisher": ""O'Reilly Media, Inc.""
}

>>> json.loads(json_str_improper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 3 column 20 (char 22)
```

Note that the `\"` sequences now are printed as `"`, the backslash is gone!

Comment: have updated the question, sorry for the accidental trailing comma, The json is valid.

Comment: thank you, defining the string as raw (`r`) as per this answer solved the problem. note the question's error message was messed up, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. If you have questions about your JSON objects, you can always validate them with [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com). In your case you have an object

```
{
"publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\"",
}
```

and you have an extra comma indicating that something else should be coming. So JSONlint yields

> Parse error on line 2:
>   ...edia, Inc.\"",    }
>   ---------------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING'

which would begin to help you find where the error was.

Removing the comma for

```
{
"publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""
}
```

yields

> Valid JSON

Update: I'm keeping the stuff in about JSONlint as it may be helpful to others in the future. As for your well formed JSON object, I have

```
import json

d = {
    "publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""
    }

print "Here is your string parsed."
print(json.dumps(d))
```

yielding

> Here is your string parsed.
>   {"publisher": "\"O'Reilly Media, Inc.\""}
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: sorry for the accidental trailing comma, the json is valid, have posted a screenshot.